# Активный слайд на slick js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3, slick.js

Всем привет. Имеется такой сея слайдер (ссылка)

Не пойму как сделать чтобы отслеживался активный слайд при нажатии на стрелки. То есть должен выделяться активный слайд внизу.

Подскажите пожалуйста, если кто знает.
Всем спасибо.

```
https://codepen.io/programmer005/pen/gOLqrdW
```

```js
$('.slider-win').slick({
    accessibility:true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    horizontalSwiping:true,
    swipe:true,
    autoplay: false,
    prevArrow: '<img src="https://img1.pngindir.com/20190707/yoe/kisspng-computer-icons-arrow-portable-network-graphics-sca-filesimpleicons-interface-arrow-pointing-left-in-5d224b7090e118.2838221815625286245934.jpg" class="slick-prev">',
    nextArrow: '<img src="https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3765-3363-4063-a137-396533353130/pngwingcom_1.png" class="slick-next">',
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
  
});

$('.slider-controll').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  vertical: false,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-win',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: false,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.slider-win{
  margin:0 auto;  
  text-align:center;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150xp;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  display: block;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide.slick-current {
  border-color: skyblue;
}


.slick-prev{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 20px;
}
.slick-prev:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-next{
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.slick-next:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-win">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
</div>
  
<div class="slider-controll">
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="3"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `asNavFor: '.slider-controll'` в `$('.slider-win').slick`:

```js
$('.slider-win').slick({
    accessibility:true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    horizontalSwiping:true,
    swipe:true,
    autoplay: false,
    prevArrow: '<img src="https://img1.pngindir.com/20190707/yoe/kisspng-computer-icons-arrow-portable-network-graphics-sca-filesimpleicons-interface-arrow-pointing-left-in-5d224b7090e118.2838221815625286245934.jpg" class="slick-prev">',
    nextArrow: '<img src="https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3765-3363-4063-a137-396533353130/pngwingcom_1.png" class="slick-next">',
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    asNavFor: '.slider-controll'
});

$('.slider-controll').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  vertical: false,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-win',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  centerMode: false,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.slider-win{
  margin:0 auto;  
  text-align:center;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150xp;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  display: block;
}

.slider-controll .slick-slide.slick-current {
  border-color: skyblue;
}


.slick-prev{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 20px;
}
.slick-prev:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slick-next{
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.slick-next:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider-win">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt="">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
</div>
  
<div class="slider-controll">
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="1"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544801568-5ec5a66bf3fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517327258734-375b7a2aa8d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjI0MX0&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1051&q=80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="3"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523053511548-d31e5927fb25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" alt=""></div>
  <div class="slider-item" data-item="4"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524701370974-bf337323869d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Comment: У меня возникает такая ошибка, когда я запускаю код на компьютере.  

slick.js:3005 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSlick' of undefined
    at S.fn.init.$.fn.slick (slick.js:3005)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (slick.js:357)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Slick.asNavFor (slick.js:356)
    at Slick.slideHandler (slick.js:2488)
    at Slick.changeSlide (slick.js:722)
    at Slick.i [as changeSlide] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Slick.goTo.Slick.slickGoTo (slick.js:1253)
    at S.fn.init.$.fn.slick (slick.js:3005)

Comment: а тут работает
codepen.io

Comment: @МагомедДжалилов, значит, Вы где-то ошиблись в коде на компьютере - проверяйте правильное написание селекторов asNavFor

Comment: Странно, я копирую тот же код..